# Copy text from textbox field to <p>

Tags: javascript, html

I understand how to copy text from one textbox to another textbox in JS, but I want to copy the text from a textbox into a paragraph. How would you do this?

Thanks

Edit:
My bad, I didn't specify well enough. I'm trying to change the textContext of a paragraph to the value of a textbox upon clicking a button. This is what I have so far:

```html
<input type="text" id="field1" value="Hello World!"><br>
<p id="field2"></p><br><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy Text</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("field2").textContext = document.getElementById("field1").value;
}
</script>
```

Anybody know why it isn't copying the value of the textbox field to the paragraph?

Comment: `<p contenteditable="true">You can edit me and paste text here.</p>` (Didn't downvoted BTW)

Comment: Post the code you tried and are having trouble with in your question please.

Comment: It works the same. Just use .textContent instead of .value.

Comment: @AlonEitan  Sorry, I didn't specify well enough. Check the edits to understand more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your purposes. You described the solution in your question, pretty much.

> change the textContext of a paragraph to the value of a textbox

```js
function myFunction() {
  var textbox = document.getElementById('field1');
  var paragraph = document.getElementById('field2');
  
  paragraph.textContent = textbox.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field1" value="Hello World!"><br>
<p id="field2"></p><br><br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy Text</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

May you want know about reactive binding.
For example using Vue.js

HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
   <p>{{ message }}</p>
   <input v-model="message">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     message: 'Hello World!'
   }
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://playcode.io/10?tabs=app.html&script.js&output)